# How do I get automated documentation to show my actual model rather than IHttpActionResult

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, xml-documentation

I have this controller which returns a product

```
    ///-----------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>   Gets a product. </summary>
    ///
    /// <param name="locationid">   The locationid. </param>
    /// <param name="productid">    The productid. </param>
    ///
    /// <returns>   The product. </returns>
    ///-----------------------------------------------------------
    [Route("{productid}", Name = "GetProductById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int locationid, string productid)
    {
      Product product = this.GetProductByID(locationid, productid);
      return this.Ok(product);
    }
```

The product model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Location{ get; set; }
    public int ProductId{ get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
}
```

However when I run my /help page and navigate to the /api/location/{locationId}/product/{productId} page, I get this result
[image: Screenshot of the Help Page showing IHttpActionResult model]

I really would rather have a link to my Product model than the IHttpActionResult model - any idea how I can do this in the XML documentation that generates the XML help file?